# Call Magic methods in Eloquent laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

i try use __call magic method for make dynamic method in laravel Eloquent.
i have blog and blog_translations table and TITLE,CONTENT must be load from blog_translations table .

> ```
> public function translations($lang = null)
> {
>     if(empty($lang)) {
>         if (!empty(Lang::getLocale())) {
>             $language = Lang::getLocale();
>         } else {
>             $language = Config::get('app.fallback_locale');
>         }
>     }else{
>         $language = $lang;
>     }
>     return $this->hasMany(Blog_Translation::class)->where('locale', $language);
> }
>
> public function __call($method,$arg)
> {
>     $filed = str_replace('get','',$method);
>     if(sizeof($arg) >= 1){
>         $lang = $arg[0];
>     }else {
>         $lang = '';
>     }
>     return $this->translations($lang)->where('name',$filed)->first()->text;
> }
> ```

in controller :

> ```
>     $blog   = Blog::find(1);
>     return $blog->getTITLE();
> ```

error :

> Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$id

with remove __call function relationship work good.

Comment: @RyanVincent in Blog model must be pass call or in cotroller?

Comment: @RyanVincent yessss,it,s work

Comment: Glad you got it working :)